# undefined method for calling methode in class

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

i try to call my methode **check_table_exists**  for check my table. This methode is on my module, and i dont understand why i get this error .

i know `@connexion` is a Mysql2::Client instance, which doesn't include the module `Sgbd`. but i dont see how to include my methode ?

```
./yamlReadFile.rb:44:in `mysql_connection': undefined method `check_table_exists' for #<Mysql2::Client:0x000000033a7750> (NoMethodError)

$LOAD_PATH << '.' 
require 'yaml'
require 'rubygems'
require 'mysql2'
require 'creatDatabase'

#binding.pry
class StreamMysql
 include Sgbd
 def mysql_connection(conf)
        @connexion = Mysql2::Client.new(:host => conf['ost'], :username => conf['user'], :password => conf['password'], :table => conf['table'], :port => conf['port'])
        if @connexion

         puts check_table_exists
         @connexion.check_table_exists

         puts "connexion etablie"

        else
         puts "error connexion"
         end


        rescue Mysql2::Error => e
          puts e.errno
          puts e.error
        @connexion.close
end

 def read_config_file
        config = YAML::load_file(File.join(__dir__, 'config.yml'))
        conf   = config['database']
        mysql_connection(conf)
 end


end
```

my module file with the mehode **check_table_exists**

```
module Sgbd

# class ModuleCreateDatabase

  def  create_database

  end

  def check_table_exists
      query=("SHOW TABLES;")
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

It’s unclear why would you want to include your module in the foreign class, but it’s doable:

```
Mysql2::Client.include Sgbd
```

The line above should be put e. g. before `class StreamMysql` declaration.

Comment: i would want a class for connection, and a module for task like ( select, update, create etc...